# Back button takes me to home screen instead of previous activity after exiting the Phone Dialer

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, apk, android-webview

In my webview android app when i click on the button that takes me to the dialer and once i exit the phone dialer app my webview apk takes me back to the dashboard screen instead of going back to the previous screen.

the backpressed() event works fine for all the rest cases but it throws me to the dashboard screen once it exits either the dialer window or the sms window

here is my shouldOverrideloading(),OnSavedInstanceState(),OnRestoredInstanceState(),OnBackPressed() codes

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX) || url.startsWith("sms:")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            webview.goBack();
            return false;
        }
        else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return false;
    }
 

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webview.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack() && !Objects.equals(webview.getUrl(), websiteURL)) {
        webview.goBack();
    }
    else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("EXIT")
                .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Help me with the solution to go back to just the previous screen after we exit the dialer window

Comment: You are referring to 'dialer window'. Is it a webpage user can navigate to in the webview? Or is it a separate Activity?

Comment: @Ruslan it is a separate Activity , that we click on the button and it takes us to dialer window and once I exit it, it redirects to the dashboard screen instead of going to the previous screen

Comment: The dialer window is the Phone dialer app . The button takes me to phone dialer and once we exit that phone dialer, t throws me to the dashboard/home screen instead of going to the previous screen . It stays on the previous screen for a split of a second but goes to the home screen eventually and I'm not able to figure out where is the process going wrong .

Comment: I see. Did you override `onResume` method of your Activity? Probably there is something which prevents staying your App when you come back? And do you set any tags to your Activity, e.g. `noHistory`?

Comment: I have set 'noHistory=false' in the activity and I haven't override onResume method

Comment: Got it. When you launch phone dialer app and go back, user usually have 2 options: press on back button (usually it is on the bottom portion of the screen) and up-navigation from toolbar. Which option are you referring to? In case with hardware back button it should go back to you Activity indeed. Btw just checked exactly the same Intent you use, and it works as expected. But up-navigation is little bit different. It is designed to navigate user back to main screen of parent app (Phone caller app in your case). Probably that is the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252849/discussion-between-noobcoderrr16-and-ruslan).

Comment: @noobcoderrr16 Did you solve your issue? If so, could you post here (as an accepted answer) the solution? Thanks.